# Delphi: Getting the right source from web pages

Tags: html, delphi, web-scraping, user-agent

I'm using Delphi and I'm trying to get the source from web pages.

My problem is that I get different sourcecode when I use Indy (idHttp) or Clever Components (clHttp) instead of IE and/or Google Chrome.

Is there any way I could retrieve a web page source with Delphi exactly the same way as the ones showing by the browsers ?

Comment: I'd like to make a suggestion about your question (have no answer for you on this, sorry). Unless there are people on SO who know exactly what you are asking about, it *seems* likely that you need to specify what particular parts IE and Google Chrome managed to show that were missing from the results returned by the Delphi components you tried.

Comment: Also, mentioning that web page URL might help

Comment: @mhoude: What do you mean by "... can handle the span tags". You just request a URL and get back a bunch of characters as response. The components do not handle any of the content of this response at all.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably because the control is sending a **User Agent string** which is different than the ones used by IE or Chrome. So in other words, the SERVER is sending back a different source than it does for IE or Chrome.

For example, In TIdDHTTP, set:

```
Request.Accept=*/*
Request.CacheControl=no-cache
Request.Connection=Keep-Alive
Request.ContentType=application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Request.AcceptEncoding=gzip, deflate
Request.UserAgent=Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Win32)
Request.Host=(web site name)
```

Comment: Note that `TIdHTTP` manages the `ContentType`, `AcceptEncoding`, and `Host` values for you.  The rest can be set manually.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, requesting the page from the component is doing the same as the browser does. Only the browser might do several more requests and other activities eg. JavaScript that might change the DOM.

Try switching off JavaScript and compare again.
If your familiar with chrome developer tools, check the raw input from the first HTTP get and compare that. If still different, then modify your request to make it identical to the chrome request.